# Could not load database driver mysqli! on opencart

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, opencart

I have downloaded opencart 2.0 yesterday for testing it and after I installed vqmod latest 2.4.1 I started receiving the error Error: Could not load database driver mysqli!. I searched regarding this error and found something related to the leading slash, but after I got an error like 'Notice: Error: Could not load class Config.php!'. Current config.php

```
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://localhost/opencart/affiliate-payments/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://localhost/opencart/affiliate-payments/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', 'F:/SERVER/htdocs/opencart/affiliate-payments/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', 'F:/SERVER/htdocs/opencart/affiliate-payments/system/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', 'F:/SERVER/htdocs/opencart/affiliate-payments/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', 'F:/SERVER/htdocs/opencart/affiliate-payments/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', 'F:/SERVER/htdocs/opencart/affiliate-payments/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', 'F:/SERVER/htdocs/opencart/affiliate-payments/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', 'F:/SERVER/htdocs/opencart/affiliate-payments/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', 'F:/SERVER/htdocs/opencart/affiliate-payments/system/download/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', 'F:/SERVER/htdocs/opencart/affiliate-payments/system/modification/');
define('DIR_LOGS', 'F:/SERVER/htdocs/opencart/affiliate-payments/system/logs/');
```

In the current configuration I get `Error: Could not load database driver mysqli!`

If I remove also the slash, like if I remove entirely `F:/SERVER/htdocs/opencart/affiliate-payments/`
I get same error `Error: Could not load database driver mysqli!`

if I remove `F:/SERVER/htdocs/opencart/affiliate-payments` I get `Notice: Error: Could not load class Config.php! in F:\SERVER\htdocs\opencart\affiliate-payments\system\startup.php on line 74`

Comment: vQmod is not guaranteed to work with unreleased OC versions, however the error you're receiving has nothing to do with vQmod - your server doesn't seem to have mysqli installed

Comment: @Jay Gilford I tried adding `define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');` and now is echoing `Error: Could not load database driver mysql!` so it's not because of that. XAMPP comes with PHP 5+ and MYSQLI so not a problem from there.

Answer (score 3):

please make sure you are using php version less than 5.5 for this open cart version else download higher open cart version

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing the following line in your config.php file which appears usually after `define('DIR_SYSTEM', '../system/');`

`define('DIR_DATABASE', '../system/database/');`

I would go back to relative paths, keep in mind there are two config files, one in the root of the site and one in admin. You need to add the '../system' in the admin one if the one in root is 'system'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I moved from one host to another.

`define('DIR_DATABASE', '/storage/content/72/2000872/itdestination.se/public_html/database/');`

I replaced it with below line

`define('DIR_DATABASE', '/storage/content/72/2000872/itdestination.se/public_html/system/database/');`

`/system` was missing in my old DIR_database.